# If $\Omega = [0,1]$ and $\mathcal{F}$ is the set of subsets $A$ such that either $A$ or $A^c$ are countable, is $\mathcal{F}$ an ($\sigma$) algebra?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I will flesh out the question here (Question taken from Rosenthal's Intro to probability theory book). (I omit parts (a) and (c))

> Suppose that $\Omega = [0,1]$ is the unit interval, and $\mathcal{F}$
>   is the set of all subsets $A$ such that either $A$ or $A^c$ is
>   countable (i.e., finite or countably infinite), and $P$ is defined by
>   $P(A) = 0$ if $A$ is countable, and $P(A) = 1$ if $A^c$ is countable.
>
> (b) Is $\mathcal{F}$ a $\sigma$-algebra?
>
> **(d) Is $P$ countably additive on $\mathcal{F}$?** meaning that if $A1,A2,... \in \mathcal{F}$ are disjoint, and if it happens that
>   $\cup_n A_n \in \mathcal{F}$, then $P(\cup_n A_n) = \sum_n P(A_n)$

I am wondering whether I am correct for b,d, and whether the (rough) proofs I provide look okay?

Thanks.

(b) Yes. $\emptyset, \Omega\in \mathcal{F}$ clearly, and $\mathcal{F}$ is clearly closed under complements (by def).

Is $\mathcal{F}$ closed under finite unions? Consider the following cases:

1. Case: $ \cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ countable,$\ A_i \in \mathcal{F}$ and $A_i$ countable $\forall i$. Then $ \cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \in \mathcal{F}$ because a countable union of countable sets is countable.
2. Case: $ \cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$, uncountable, $\ A_i \in \mathcal{F}$ and $A_i$ are countable $\forall i$ except one. WLOG assume $A_n$ is uncountable.Then $A_n^c$ is countable because $A_n \in \mathcal{F}$ and thus $ \cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \in \mathcal{F}$ because $ (\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i)^c=  \cap_{i=1}^\infty A_i^c$ which cannot have more elements than the smallest set, which is the countable $A_n^c$ (because assumed that is the only uncountable set, so all other $A_i^c$ are uncountable). This argument can be expanded by induction to the case with more than one uncountable set.

(d) Yes. Let $A_1,A_2,\dots \in \mathcal{F}$ be disjoint such that $\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \in \mathcal{F}.$There are two cases to consider:

1. Case: $\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ is countable.

Then $A_i$ is countable $\forall i$ and then
$$ 
P(\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i) = 0 = \sum_{i=1}^\infty P(A_i)
$$

2. Case: $\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ is uncountable.($(\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i)^c$ is countable.).

Then at least one $A_i$ is uncountable, because if all $A_i$ we countable then the countable union would have to be countable.. Let $A_{n_0}$ be uncountable.

We will show that only one $A_i$ can be infinite:
Consider $n\not = n_0$. Then, by assumption, $A_n \cap A_{n_0} = \emptyset \implies A_n \subseteq A_{n_0}^c$ but $A_{n_0}^c$ is countable, which implies that $A_n$ is countable. Thus, only $A_{n_0}$ is infinite. Therefore,
    $$
P(\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i) = 1 +0 = \left(\sum_{n \not = n_0} 0\right) +P(A_{n_0}) = \left(\sum_{n \not = n_0} P(A_n)\right) +P(A_{n_0}) = \sum_{n =1}^\infty P(A_n)
     $$
Thus, $P$ is countably additive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(b) Your cases 1. and 2. are not exaustive, since we could have $\bigcup A_i$ uncountable, and more than one of the $A_i$ being uncountable. The rest of the arguments are more-or-less ok, but it's quite confusing to read. I'll write a version here, which you will probably recognize as saying basically the same things as you did:

Case 2. $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ is uncountable.

Then at least one the $A_i$ is uncountable (because a countable union of countable sets is countable). Let $A_{n_0}$ be uncountable. Since $A_{n_0}\in\mathcal{F}$, then $A_{n_0}^c$ is countable. Since $(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i)^c=\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i^c\subseteq A_{n_0}^c$, then $(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i)^c$ is countable, so $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\in\mathcal{F}$.

(d) Again your second case is confusing, and you're using "infinite" to mean "uncountable", apparently, which is **wrong**. The arguments are ok, though, if you correct the usage of the words "infinite".

Also, be careful in the order of the elements in the equation you wrote: You should write "$0+1$" instead of "$1+0$" to have the other terms in the correct order.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time both to answer to to provide helpful comments.

Comment: @Luiz. I think you meant to say "Since $(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i)^c=\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i^c\subseteq A_{n_0}^c$," and not "Since $(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i)^c=\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i^c\subseteq A_{n_0}$,"

Comment: @TryingHardToBecomeAGoodPrSlvr Yes, I did. Corrected ;)